# Errors with xhtml

Tags: xhtml

I started to learn xhtml as it's the first topic from the book I'm reading and tried creating a simple form to enter just a name.
This is half of what I copied from the book only keeping the input text field:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<head>
  <title>Enter Customer Name</title>
</head>

<body> 
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
  <h:messages/>
  <h:form id="test">
     <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="first name:"></h:outputLabel>
     <h:inputText id="firstname" label="first name" value="#{test.firstname}" required="true">
     <f:validateLength minimum="2" maximum="10">
     </f:validateLength>
     </h:inputText>
   </h:form>   
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open it int he browser, this is what I get

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdGN7.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "When I run it" - what do you mean, precisely? XHTML files are not executable (although I see `#{test.firstname}` which kind of suggests Ruby should be involved somehow). I assume you mean "open it in a browser"; how do you do this, is the file local or served by a web server, if so, which (Apache, nginx, a Ruby script acting as a server...)? The root cause for your result is likely the browser getting the mimetype `text/xml`, when it should be `application/xhtml+xml`, but it's impossible to tell you how to do it unless you answer more details on how the file got delivered to your browser.

Comment: @Amadan yes, I mean open in the browser and it's local and the web server is apache tomcat. Is this all you need?

Comment: The xmlns attribute is not OK. It should be `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` rather than `"http://w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Comment: @Amadan saving the OP's source as a .xhtml file and opening it in the browser does result in the error. Correcting it will give the desired result.

Comment: @MrLister now all i get is a blank screen.

Comment: @Biswajit Yes, this code is actually JSF, which is supposed to be processed on the server side. The book should have told you that.

Comment: @MrLister I have a question, Should I save it as xhtml or jsf?
And I did run it from apache tomcat.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. Maybe [this page](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaServerFaces/article.html) will help. But what you should really do is add the tags `tomcat` and `jsf` to this question, so you can attract the experts.

Answer (score 0):

Your document isn't XHTML.

The Doctype claims it is, but then you have a bunch of errors and non-XHTML content.

The browser is parsing the document in XML mode, which is a good first step if you were actually writing XHTML.

As pointed out in a comment:

> The xmlns attribute is not OK. It should be `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` rather than `"http://w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Since you got it wrong, your default namespace isn't recognised as XHTML and the browser treats it as an unknown XML format with no special handling. This is why you get view of the XML node tree.

When you correct that, your document begins to be parsed as XHTML.

> now all i get is a blank screen

This is because the only XHTML elements you have are the root element, the `head` and its descendants, and the `body`.

Everything else (e.g. `h:form`) is not XHTML. You have imported it from the `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` namespace (except for those parts you imported from the `http://java.sun.com/jsf/core` namespace). (Note that this is forbidden by your choice of Doctype).

Web browsers do not know what to do with elements from those namespaces, so they get inserted into the DOM but are not rendered.

You need to either:

- Determine what tool those elements are designed for use with and use that instead of a web browser. (It is possible that that tool outputs code you can use with a web browser).
- Write code using languages designed for use with a web browser. That could be real XHTML, but the benefits of it only apply to rare edge cases and you would almost certainly be better off writing HTML.

Comment: Yes. But technically, the output is empty because none of the elements in the body have any textual content, not because they are not XHTML!

Comment: @MrLister — It looks like the goal is to create a form. If the `h:inputText` was an `input` element then it would show up without having any textual content.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It runs fine now,switched to net beans it' good now :D